# How to cite all entries and show labels?

Tags: biblatex

The command `\nocite{*}` cites all entries but does not show labels in text. I want similar command to show both labels and bibliography entries

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\bibliography{biblatex-examples.bib} 

\begin{document} 
    
    Basmah
    
    \nocite{*}
    
    \newrefcontext[sorting=ydnt]
    \printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: How about `\cite{*}`?

Comment: You could use the [`citeall`-package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/citeall) with `\citeall` for this. But it was not updated for a while.